Delay subscription in Zoho Billing
I want to delay my subscription start day. Means If I buy the subscription today and want to start the subscription on 20 days delay. How can this be achieved in Zoho Billing on hosted plan page?
On hosted plan page here is the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/btwMPRmWmg6v I need user can enter the start date for start their subscription.
User can pay at that time but will be able to pick start date for their subscription.
Here is what I am trying to do:
I am doing by adding custom field in customer form: https://prnt.sc/uTXbyL1nTEGm
How can I link this start date on subscription creation.
Because this date is stored in the created customer information.
